# How to embed a video player when posting a message with Yammer API?

Tags: yammer, yammer-api

I can't figure it out how to embed a video player when posting a message with Yammer API.

I have been testing the Yammer API with postman:

[image: screenshot: postman]

As response, I got "400 bad request":

```
{
    "body": [
        "Please include a message"
    ],
    "code": "body_blank"
}
```

If I just paste the video url in "body", I will get "201 created". But in Yammer, the post looks like:

[image: Screenshot:Yammer]

I would like the post looks similar to this:

[image: Screenshot: Yammer2]

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. Add following parameters in the request body:

[image: Screenshot: postman]

Result:

[image: Screenshot: yammer]